# Chrome extension: declarativeNetRequest isn't matching RuleCondition

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to use [RuleCondition.domains](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-RuleCondition) to match only the network requests originating from my chrome extension page located at `chrome-extension://xxx/app/index.html#/page/some-page`?

```json
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "responseHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "x-frame-options",
          "operation": "remove"
        },
        {
          "header": "frame-options",
          "operation": "remove"
        }
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "domains": ["chrome-extension://*/*"],
      "resourceTypes": [
        "sub_frame"
      ]
    }
  }
```

The problem with the snippet above is that the match pattern for `chrome-extension://*/*` isn't applied and the rule never activates. Removing "domains" property solves the problem, but I would prefer to use this rule only where it is needed.

I also tried chrome-extension, chrome-extension//*, extension id... none matched

Manifest v3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found a solution:

USE THE CHROME EXTENSION ID ALONE, FOR EXAMPLE:

```
"domains": ["jnejifelmoaaoghdgaoikmblgcbmgcdn"]
```